# Link URL Breaking while changing ID to some other string

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was having and ID in the URL example service-detail/1 which was working fine later I redirected the route to service-detail/abc not the url is not working I am not sure what is the error

I am getting the routes like

```
<Route  path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/service"}`}
                            element={<ServicePage />}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path={`${
                                process.env.PUBLIC_URL +
                                "/service-details/:title"
                            }`}
                            element={<ServiceDetails />}
                        />
```

In console I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bodyBottom')
    at ServiceDetailsContainer (index.jsx:26:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <ServiceDetailsContainer> component:

    at ServiceDetailsContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10955:5)
    at div
    at Layout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12287:5)
    at ServiceDetails (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14746:67)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60539:5)
    at NavScrollTop (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4067:51)
    at Wrapper (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4141:78)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60472:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59948:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bodyBottom')
    at ServiceDetailsContainer (index.jsx:26:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

SO I saw the error was in ServiceDetailsContainer but I could not find it

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ServiceDetails from "../../../components/service-details";
import ServiceCate from "../../../components/sidebar/service-cate";
import ServiceData from "../../../data/service.json";
import Brochure from "../../../components/sidebar/brochure";

const ServiceDetailsContainer = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <div className="single-service section-py">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-8">
                        <ServiceDetails data={data} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 offset-xl-1">
                        <div className="sidbar-widget float-start w-100">
                            <ServiceCate data={ServiceData} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="sidbar-widget float-start w-100 mt-10 mb-10">
                            <Brochure />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <p>{data.bodyBottom}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ServiceDetailsContainer.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object,
};

export default ServiceDetailsContainer;
```

Json File

```
"id": 1,
        "icon": "./images/service/icon/1.png",
        "smallIcon": "/images/service/icon/small/1.png",
        "image": "./images/service/3.png",
        "title": "Banking",
        "categories": [
            "Digital ",           
        ],
        "excerpt": "Account Opening
```

Comment: Check the `data` prop passing to `<ServiceDetailsContainer />`, it is `undefined` at some point: when the `id` param is not found in `service.json`.

Comment: const { title } = useParams();
    const serviceId = parseInt(title, 10);
    const data = ServiceData.filter((service) => service.id === serviceId);
    console.log(parseInt(title, 10));

I am getting NAN serviceId  where as when I console Logged Title I was getting the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For URL path `"/service-detail/abc"` the `title` param is not a number, so `const serviceId = parseInt(title, 10);` fails converting to a number type. For id type values you generally want to go the other way and convert to strings for the strict equality check.

Example:

```
const { title } = useParams(); // <-- params are always string type
const data = ServiceData.filter((service) => String(service.id) === title);
```

OFC, you *could* also use loose equality (`==`) which will attempt a type conversion for comparison.

```
const { title } = useParams(); // <-- params are always string type
const data = ServiceData.filter((service) => service.id == title);
```

```js
console.log(1 === '1');         // false
console.log(String(1) === '1'); // true
console.log(1 == '1');          // true
```

See [Equality comparison and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for a more in-depth explanation.

Additionally, because it is entirely possible for the `data` array result from filtering to be an empty array, i.e. no matches found, the UI code should handle this case and conditionally render some fallback UI instead of attempting to access into the null/undefined data object since it doesn't exist.